# PHP: find out if a property is dynamic or declared

Tags: php

Is there a quick way to tell if the property of a class is dynamic?

Consider the following code:

```php
class Foo {
   public $bar;
}

$obj = new Foo;
$obj->baz = 1;
```

How can I tell that `$bar` is declared and `$baz` is dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two parts, first get the class variables from `$obj` and then the object variables

```
$static = get_class_vars(get_class($obj));
$all = get_object_vars($obj);
```

(using `get_class()` allows you to make it based on any object as it fetches the class of the object rather than hard coding it)

Then the difference between the two are the dynamic variables...

```
$dynamic = array_diff_key($all, $static);
```

So for your example...

```
print_r($static);
print_r($dynamic);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [bar] => 
)

Array
(
    [baz] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of function is_dynamic():

```php
function is_dynamic($object, $property_name)
{
   return  array_key_exists($property_name, get_object_vars($object)) &&
          !array_key_exists($property_name, get_class_vars(get_class($object)));
}
```